# call a static method (of another class) within main method

Tags: java

I have the following program where I have to return an array after performing certain operation on 2 arrays (display elements of Array a that are not in Array b),

Here's the code

```
class Main {
    static int[] result(int a[], int b[]) {
        int count, x, m = 0;
        int d[] = new int[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            count = 0;
            x = a[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
                if (b[j] == x) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count == 0) {
                //System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
                d[m] = a[i];
                m++;
            }
        }
        return d;
    }
}

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a[] = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9 };
        int b[] = new int[] { 0, 2, 6, 8 };
        int c[] = result(a, b);
        for (int k = 0; k < c.length; k++) {
            System.out.print(c[k] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

The following error occurs:

> HelloWorld.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
>           int c[]=result(a,b);
>                   ^
>     symbol:   method result(int[],int[])
>     location: class HelloWorld
>   1 error

Comment: to call a static method use <Classname>.<methodname>. In your case Main.result(a, b);

Answer (score 1):

To call a static method of another class, you prefix the method name with the name of the class:

```
int c[] = Main.result(a, b);
// -------^^^^^
```

Comment: When I'm returning the array, I have declared the size of array 'd' to be 100. Is there a way to allocate size dynamically?

Comment: @sree - Just use any expression instead of `100` in `int d[] = new int[100];` But that still requires that you know the size you want in advance. You might use a `List` if you don't know the size in advance (which I think you don't). Or you could make `d` the same size as `a` (`int d[] = new int[a.length];`), then if you didn't need all of it you could copy to a smaller array before returning.